# AWS elasticsearch disable replication of all indices

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, aws-elasticsearch

I am using a single node AWS ES cluster. Currently, its health status is showing yellow which is obvious because there is no other node to which Amazon ES can assign a replica. I want to set the replication of all my current and upcoming indices to `0`. I have indices created in this pattern:

```
app-one-2021.02.10
app-two-2021.01.11
so on...
```

These indices are currently having `number_of_replicas` set to `1`. To disable replication for all indices I am throwing a PUT request in index pattern:

```
PUT /app-one-*/_settings
{
 "index" : {
  "number_of_replicas":0
 }
}
```

Since I am using a wildcard here so it should set `number_of_replicas` to `0` in all the matching indices, which it is doing successfuly.

But if any new index is created in the future let's say app-one-2021.03.10. Then the `number_of_replicas` is again set to 1 in this index.

Every time I have to run a PUT request to set `number_of_replicas` to `0` which is tedious. Why new indices are not automatically taking `number_of_replicas` to `0` even if I am using a wildcard (*) in my PUT request.

Is there any way to completely set replication (`number_of_replicas` to `0`) to 0, and doesn't matter if it's a new index or an old index. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the way is to define index templates.

Before Elasticsearch v7.8, you could only use the `_template` API ([see docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.11/indices-templates-v1.html)). E.g., in your case, you can create a template matching all the app-* indices:

```
PUT _template/app_settings
{
  "index_patterns": ["app-*"],
  "settings": {
    "number_of_replicas": 0
  }
}
```

Since Elasticsearch v7.8, the old API is still supported but deprecated, and you can use the `_index_template` API instead ([see docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.11/index-templates.html)).

```
PUT _index_template/app_settings
{
  "index_patterns": ["app-*"],
  "template": {
    "settings": {
      "number_of_replicas": 0
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Update**: add code snippets for both `_template` and `_index_template` API.

Comment: Firstly in AWS elasticsearch we've to use `_template` instead of `_index_template`. Secondly, I have tried creating a template, but still all my new indices come up with `number_of_replicas` to `1`. Any clue what's wrong?

Comment: AWS Elasticsearch is based on Open Distro, which also differentiates between _template and _index_template starting from Elasticsearch v7.8 (https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/elasticsearch/index-templates/). Can you post your template somewhere, so we can have a look? Are there other templates that match the same index pattern? If it is so, you may want to increase the value of the `priority` parameter of your custom template (see docs)

Comment: No, I don't have other templates for the same index patterns so doesn't matter the priority. One thing that I noticed is my `.kibana` index has `auto_expand_replicas` set to `0-1` which means replicate if you can. Should I set this to `0`?

Comment: When I do `curl <my-es-domain>/_template/app_settings?pretty`. The setting section shows null i.e, `{}` instead of `{number_of_replicas : 0}`. Why is that even when I make the correct PUT request?

Comment: Just to be sure, do you have read/write permissions on templates?

Comment: Maybe yes. But I don't know fully. How can I check that?

Comment: Nevertheless, I got it working. Just remove the `template {}` section from the above PUT request and define `settings` without using `template {}`. Can you please edit your answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: Hi.. ok, but I'll keep both options, one using `_index_template` and the other using the legacy `_template` :)